# Is there a way to expose User edit history in Control Panel (similar to Entries)?

Tags: craft3, users, dashboard, revisions

- "Users" version should work like "Entries" versioning work
  [image]

Comment: Hi Arshit, just wanted to clarify so that we can help you get some answers. Are you asking how you can add version histories on Users in Craft CMS, similar to how entries have version histories?

Comment: Yes, And It's possible to display this histories on dashboard ? @cherrykoda

Comment: Got it, I've updated your question to help others on the platform, this seems more like a feature request so I should also remind you that Stack Exchange is community run, you can always request features on the Craft github where devs will see it. https://github.com/craftcms/cms Cheers!